# MapFragment. When inflating a layout: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-maps

I get the next error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added.

This is a layout getting inflated each time I change  tab, as seen in this photo:

![FirstTab]http://prntscr.com/h4e8pc

![SecondTab]http://prntscr.com/h4ebyn

So i get the idea of the problem, but I've tried many ways to fix it with no result. I've tried to use `.replace` instead of `.add`, that way it doesnt crash but the map is not loaded. And also tried to delete the fragment as soon as I switch to that tab but the result is similar to the `.replace` one.

```
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:

                frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
                frame.removeAllViewsInLayout();
                LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                              .inflate(R.layout.activity_prueba_dashboard, frame, true);

                fragmentTransaction =
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content2, mMapFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                mMapFragment.getMapAsync(my_maps_class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's much cleaner to use viewpager in that situation. Check this code :

```
public class HomeViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public static final int FRAGMENT_A_INDEX = 0;
    public static final int FRAGMENT_B_INDEX = 1;
    public static final int FRAGMENT_C_INDEX = 2;

    public static final int FRAGMENTS_COUNT = 3;

    public HomeViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case FRAGMENT_A_INDEX:
                return FragmentA.newInstance();
            case FRAGMENT_B_INDEX:
                return FragmentB.newInstance();
            case FRAGMENT_C_INDEX:
                return FragmentC.newInstance();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return FRAGMENTS_COUNT;
    }
}
```

and then link the adapter with the ViewPager in the hosting appcompat activity as here :

```
HomeViewPagerAdapter homeTabsAdapter = new HomeViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
homeTabsViewPager.setAdapter(homeTabsAdapter);
```

and you can easily switch between fragments by calling :

```
homeTabsViewPager.setCurrentItem(HomeViewPagerAdapter.FRAGMENT_A_INDEX, false);
```

Comment: Hi Islam, thank you so much. I must ask something else, where do I add the content of each fragment? :) Thank you!

Comment: You will create separate fragments each has his own .java & .xml file and have an the main activity holding the viewpager which controls theses fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You seen to be trying replacing the content of the same Fragment, in this case you dont need the FragmentTransaction.

The solution is to create a second fragment on which you have the map, in this case the Transaction is needed.